# How to use a Twig variable as View name in drupal_view() Twig Tweaks function?

Tags: theming

This works:

```
{{ drupal_view('nursing_resource_blog_teasers', 'block_1') }
```

But this doesn't:

```
{% set view_name = "nursing_resource_blog_teasers" %}
{{ drupal_view(view_name , 'block_1') }
```

It appears that drupal_view() isn't allowing a variable as the View name. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I forgot about the tags in the field output.

This solved it for me:

```
{% set view_name = content.field_blog_teaser_block|render|striptags|trim %}
```